# The light hidden in Torah?

Tags: torah-study, commentaries, parashat-bereishit, lighting, zohar

In Bereshit 1:3-4 there is light(ness), and HaShem saw that it was good and seperated it from the dark(ness).

I read (Baal Shem Tov, Zohar), that HaShem hid this light in the Torah? Could someone please explain me what this (the light and it's hiding within Torah) means?

Comment: Perhaps light is a word which is used to speak about wisdom

Comment: Ecclesiastes 2, 3: Then I saw that wisdom excels folly, as far as light excels darkness.

Comment: see Derech Etz Chaim by the Ramchal

Comment: את האור in gematria/hebrew numerical value is 613. there are 613 mitzvos/commandments in the torah.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps surprisingly, this is discussed in Reshimot Shiurim of Rav Soloveitchik to Berakhot 34a. He writes that the "hidden light" is the light of knowledge that is found in the Torah and will be fully expressed in the future epoch. Particularly, it refers to an understanding of the underlying philosophy of Halakha.

> ו**הסוד שבההלכה היא השקפת העולם של ההלכה** - והיא בחינת הנשמה של התורה. וזהו באמת הענין של סתרי תורה. וזהו בחינת יינה של תורה דיין נמשל לסוד...ואילו גוף ההלכות נמשלו ללחם ובשר וכמש"כ הרמב"ם (פ"ד מהל' יסודי התורה הי"ג)...וכתיב "ולחם לבב אנוש יסעד" דיהודי צריך לדעת גופן של ההלכות כדי לחיות - כמו שלחם היא מצרכי החיים הבסיסים. אמנם לגבי יין כתיב "יין ישמח לבב אנוש" - ש**אם יודעים הסודות והשקפת העולם של התורה** זה מביא אדם לידי שמחה, ש**ע"י הבנת השקפת התורה יודע איך לחיות ולהתנהג. שהתורה מדריכתו בכל צעד**...וי"ל דזהו כוונת ריב"ל דפירש שעין לא ראתה וכו' דהיינו השכר שבעוה"ב וזהו יין המשומר מששת ימי בראשית - דיין המשומר היינו סודות התורה, **וזהו בחינת האור הגנוז מששת ימי בראשית, דהכוונה היא לאור הדעת, ויתגלה לעת"ל בעוה"ב** וכדכתיב "כי מלאה כל הארץ דעה את ה' כמים לים מכסים", **דבעוה"ז יש רק גילוי ניצוצות של האור הגנוז ולעת"ל יתגלה האור עצמו** - דיתגלה כל סודות וחכמת התורה.
>
> The secret of halakha is the weltanschauung of halakha...if one knows the secrets and outlooks of the Torah...through understanding the outlook of the Torah, one knows how to live and behave, for the Torah directs him at each step...And this is the characteristic of the light hidden from the six days of creation; that the intent is to the light of knowledge, and it will be revealed in the future in the future epoch...For in this world, there is only a revelation of sparks of the hidden light, but in the future, the light itself will be revealed. (My translation of the bolded portions).

More broadly, R. Isaiah Horowitz, writes in his *Sh'nei Luhot Hab'rit* (Toldot Adam: Beit Hokhmah; second: 189) that the Oral Law is encoded in the Written Law. This is the intent of hidden light (ibid 191):

> שמרומז כל תורה שבעל פה בתורה שבכתב...וזהו ענין אור הגנוז בחמשה חומשי תורה
>
> That the entire Oral Law is hinted to in the Written Law...And this is the idea of the light which is hidden in the Pentateuch.

Comment: That is surprising, considering Rav Soloveitchik was no where near a chassidic rebbe or kabbalist!

Comment: Indeed. However, he did famously learn Tanya from his Habad melamed in Khatslavitch, and initiated a failed attempt at a summer shiur in Likkutei Torah. He was certainly familiar with Kabbalah.